# Disable laptop keyboard to only use USB keyboard

Tags: linux, boot, keyboard, console, usb-device

I need to disable my laptop's keyboard so that keyboard can only be used via USB. I am not using X, I am on the Linux console. The solution should be able to start as early in the boot process as possible, as the problem with my internal keyboard often affects inputting the password to my encrypted partition.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of crude, but why not just blacklist the atkbd driver.

```
echo blacklist atkbd > /etc/modprobe.d/no-atkbd.conf
```

You'll probably need to rebuild your initrd to make sure it gets blacklisted very early on in the boot process.

Comment: How can I know if I did this correctly? It has not disabled the keyboard.

Comment: If you run `lsmod`, do you see atkbd in the list of modules?  Also, you can explicitly remove it with `rmmod atkbd` to see if this solution even works.  It could be that your OS distro just always loads this module, or that it compiles it into the kernel instead of as a module.

Comment: This also disables the USB keyboard.

Comment: Ah, bummer.  What about loading the i8042 module with nokbd=1, or booting with `i8042.nokbd=1`?

Answer (score -1):

Run the command in the terminal:

```
xinput list
```

It get you list of devices.  Than you can disable some of them by id:

```
xinput set-prop 10 "Device Enabled" 0
```

Comment: OP is not using X.